# Distribution build for In-App purchase still points to sandbox server

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In-App purchase and it is tested using Developer provisioning profile. At the time of purchase it shows [Environment : Sandbox]. Works fine.

But after that I created a build with Ad Hoc Distribution profile. While testing In-App purchase it also shows [Environment : Sandbox]. Is that the expected behavior ? 
Will [Environment: Sandbox] go away once the application is accepted into the App Store?

Comment: What does it say if you are logged in to app store with a non tester account?